# how to join a collection and sort it, while limiting results in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sorting, paging, nosql

lets say I have 2 collections wherein each document may look like this:

Collection 1:

```
target:
      _id,
      comments:
      [
       { _id,
         message,
         full_name
       },
       ...
      ]
```

Collection 2:

```
user:
        _id,
        full_name,
        username
```

I am paging through comments via $slice, let's say I take the first 25 entries.
From these entries I need the according usernames, which I receive from the second collection. What I want is to get the comments sorted by their reference username. The problem is I can't add the username to the comments because they may change often and if so, I would need to update all target documents, where the old username was in.
I can only imagine one way to solve this. Read out the entire full_names and query them in the user collection. The result would be sortable but it is not paged and so it takes a lot of resources to do that with large documents.

Is there anything I am missing with this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

If comments are an embedded array, you will have to do work on the client side to sort the comments array unless you store it in sorted order. Your application requirements for username force you to either read out all of the usernames of the users who commented to do the sort, or to store the username in the comments and have (much) more difficult and expensive updates.

Sorting and pagination don't work unless you can return the documents in sorted order. You should consider a different schema where comments form a separate collection so that you can return them in sorted order and paginate them. Store the username in each comment to facilitate the sort on the MongoDB side. Depending on your application's usage pattern this might work better for you.

It also seems strange to sort on usernames and expect/allow usernames to change frequently. If you could drop these requirements it'd make your life easier :D